# Изменить размер и положение изображения используя tkinter python

Tags: python, gui, изображения, tkinter

Я пишу маленькое приложение на python3, мне необходимо вывести изображение на экран около текста.

```
from tkinter import * 
...
img = PhotoImage(file = './arr.png')
...
textARR=Label(screen, image=img, text=arr,font="TimesNewRoman 16",fg="yellow",bg="#1c1c1c")
...
textARR.place(x=410,y=430)
```

И после этого открывается окно с картиной в настоящий размер.
Подскажите как его переместить на определённые координаты и задать размер.

Comment: _"И после этого открывается окно с картиной в настоящий размер."_ после чего?

Comment: После того как я запускаю программу, думаю уже можно закрыть, т.к. разобрался. Решилось это изменением размера изображения в графическом редакторе и созданием объекта содержащего в себе только изображение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изменить размер можно так:

```
image = Image.open(Image_Location)
image = image.resize((250, 250), Image.ANTIALIAS) ## The (250, 250) is (height, width)
self.pw.pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
```